# Zero subtotal payment method not showing up in one page checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-methods

Even though I have zero subtotal payment enabled it will not show up when one page checkout is enabled. If I disable one page checkout then zero subtotal payment is then shown as an option.

Can anyone suggest any reasons for this?

Comment: may the class Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Free rewrite by any 3rd partly module.. that may be create issue.So ,please chgeck

Comment: I did a search on the whole project and the only class is in \httpdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Free.php

Comment: Did you check if (whyever on earth) the Zero Subtotal Payment method is supported by your onepage checkout? Maybe ask the extension provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer myself. I had [currency manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/niro/extension/5823/et_currencymanager) installed and had decimal precision set to 6 decimal places. This caused the grand total to actually be (float) 1.0e-6 which caused core magento to error.

If I drop the precision to 4 decimal places then all works well